# Big-O complexity of this algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, big-o

CODE:

```
void fun(int n){
    if(n>2){
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            j=0;
            while(j<n){
                cout<<j;
                j++;
            }
        }
        fun(n/2);
    }
}
```

Here's what I think:
The recursive part is running log(n) times ?
and during each recursive call, the for loop will run n^2 times, with n changing to half in each recursive call. 
So is it n^2 + (n^2)/4 + (n^2)/16 + ... + 1?

Answer (score 3):

You are right, so the big(O) is n^2 since the sum of the series n^2 + (n^2)/4 + (n^2)/16 + ... + 1 never exceeds 2n^2

Comment: it could/would still be in O(n^2) even if it exceeded 2n^2.

Answer (score 2):

The number of writes to `cout` is given by the following recurrence:

```
T(N) = N² + T(N/2).
```

By educated guess, `T(N)` can be a quadratic polynomial. Hence

```
T(N) = aN²+bN+c = N² + T(N/2) = N² + aN²/4+bN/2+c.
```

By identification, we have

```
3a/4 = 1
b/2 = 0
c = c.
```

and

```
T(N) = 4N²/3 + c.
```

With `T(2)= 0`,

```
T(N) = 4(N²-4)/3
```

which is obviously `O(N²)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple mathematics. The complexity is n^2 + (n^2)/4 + (n^2)/16 + ... + 1. It is (n² * (1 + 1/4+ ...)) . And the maths says that the infinite serie converges to 4/3 (the formula is: 1 / (1 - 1/4)).

It gives actually O(n2).

Comment: Thank you for your help!